# Review/Checkout page to see selected items. WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf application which helps customers choose a paint colour for their house. Please see image and code below.

[image: PAGE 1 - CHOOSE COLOUR]

code behind

```
private void REDBUTTONPICKER_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var brush = new ImageBrush();
        brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"c:\users\user1\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WpfApplication7\paintpicker\RED.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
        REDCOLOURPREVIEW.Background = brush;
    }
```

buttons

```
<Button x:Name="REDBUTTONPICKER" Content="RED" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="65" Margin="46,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="79" Click="REDBUTTONPICKER_Click">
    <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="c:\users\user1\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WpfApplication7\paintpicker\RED.jpg"/>
    </Button.Background>
    </Button>
```

when the customer clicks review I want the colours picked on the previous page to show in the boxes on the "YOUR CHOSEN COLOURS" page. Please see image below.

[image: PAGE 2]

The four boxes are buttons.

Comment: what is the issue or problems you are facing?

Comment: @ChandreshKhambhayata no issue as such, but as the question states "when the customer clicks review I want the colours picked on the previous page to show in the boxes on page 2" - How will I get the colours selected on page 1, to show in page 2

Comment: You really have a JPEG to show an area that is filled with a color? Use a Rectangle and set its Fill property to a SoldColorBrush, e.g. one of the predefined ones in the Brushes class.

Comment: @Clemens I have used a JPEG because eventually as the application progresses, different paint patterns will be used. Such as 'Leopard Print', and the solid color brush will not suffice

Comment: What do you mean by pages? Are these separate windows? Tabs? Overlapping Grids?  

Really you should just be able to add the colors selected to a List() object then pass that to whatever "Page2" so it can display them.

Comment: Show more code, such as how the chosen colors boxes are bound.

Comment: @OmegaMan Please see revised question

Comment: Are you familiar with MVVM? Basically you need to keep the user selection in a View Model, and bind it to the chosen color boxes.

Comment: @OmegaMan I know what it is, but I do not know how to use it or how it would work

Answer (score 0):

One way of resolving this is to use the `MVVM` pattern where each of the chosen colors will be bound to properties on the `VM`. In the selection of the color, it will also set the current *unset* chosen color to change.

---

To get an understanding of MVVM I have written a blog article

[Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017)

which can get you started on creating a basic MVVM architecture to work with.